# fabric hangs while excuting remote bash script

Tags: python, bash, fabric

I have a bash script named `ssadmin.sh`, it manages another script `sscounter.sh` .
I am using fabric to excute `ssadmin.sh`.

Without `pty=False`:

```
def ts1():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run("chmod 775 %s" % 'ssadmin.sh')
        run("%s start" % 'ssadmin.sh')
```

`sscounter.sh` even can not start, but cmd would not be hanged:

```
root@ubuntu-1404:~# /mithril/scripts/ss-bash/ssadmin.sh status
ssserver not running
sscounter.sh not running
```

with `pty=False`:

```
def ts1():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run("chmod 775 %s" % 'ssadmin.sh')
        run("%s start" % 'ssadmin.sh', pty=False)



root@ubuntu-1404:~# /mithril/scripts/ss-bash/ssadmin.sh status
ssserver not running
10670 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash /mithril/scripts/ss-bash/sscounter.sh
sscounter.sh is running
```

sscounter.sh started, but cmd hangs:

```
E:\[Sync]\project\walbk\fab>fab ts1
[192.168.1.181] Executing task 'ts1'
[192.168.1.181] run: chmod 775 /mithril/scripts/ss-bash/ssadmin.sh
[192.168.1.181] run: /mithril/scripts/ss-bash/ssadmin.sh start
[192.168.1.181] out: stdin: is not a tty
[192.168.1.181] out:  9915 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash /mithril/scripts/ss-bash/sscounter.sh
[192.168.1.181] out: sscounter.sh鍚姩涓?..
[192.168.1.181] out: 10670 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash /mithril/scripts/ss-bash/sscounter.sh
[192.168.1.181] out: sscounter.sh宸插惎鍔?
[192.168.1.181] out:                 (hang at here)
```

1.why fabric hangs?

2.`fabric pty description`:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/interactivity.html#echoes

`pty is present to echo a user’s stdin`, why `sscounter.sh`wouldn't start when `pty=True`?

Comment: what is in sscounter.sh?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham it is used to count network traffic  https://github.com/hellofwy/ss-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a glance of your code, since you don't need to print out anything in `sscounter.sh`, there is one quick solution for the hanging issue: changing `( $DIR/sscounter.sh ) &` to `( $DIR/sscounter.sh ) >/dev/null 2>&1 &`.

When you did not redirect the stdout, fabric will wait for it and since your `sscounter.sh` will not exit fabric seems hanging.

If you run `ssadmin.sh`(the version without stdout redirected) remotely like this: `ssh user@remote-host 'bash ssadmin.sh'`, it will hang too for same reason. Otherwise if you are using `ssh -t user@remote-host 'bash ssadmin.sh'`, it will not hang.

I think use fabric with `pty=True` and `pty=False` is just like using `ssh` with and without `-t` option.

Comment: It works like a charm!Thank you. But I still wonder why `sscounter.sh` can not start when `pty=True`?

Comment: @Mithril `sscounter.sh` is started at first, but killed after the session terminated. You can use `(nohup $DIR/sscounter.sh) &` instead when `pty=True`

Comment: Thank you for you kind explaination!